# 2D array, it is possible with just Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I have to do an exercise but I'm not sure if it can be done with just Javascript, I'll write it down here:

> You will get 3 numbers n, m, k from the user by using prompt dialogs. Number n determines the dimension of a table or a 2D array. m determines the value that the first element (with position 0,0) should take. Then by walking diagonally through the table or array, you should increment the value m by k. Also you should fill each row and column by values which are 1 less than their previous element. After filling all the elements, you should output the table or the array on the screen. Here is an example:

[image: Example]

So the question is, do I have to do it with PHP? In that case, could you help me?

Comment: I smell... homeworks.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that, but it's for a client, he is a teacher

Comment: "it's for a client, he is a teacher" is that what you call homeworks? LOL

Comment: Client is a teacher. That's new. Regardless, it can be done in JavaScript.

Comment: Allright, but how do you set the number of rows with just Javascript?

Comment: By the way, seriously speaking: you should at least try to write some code and show us what you achieved so far. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing site when you can ask people to do the job for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: I just need to know how to set the number of rows with Javascript, that's my question, the rest I can do it easily

Comment: just an ruff approximation, procedure looks like `for(i=10;i<5;i--){for(e=n-i;e<n;n++){array[n][n]=e+k}}` .. sure its possible in javascript

Comment: I mean if it's possible to visually create the table, maybe I explained myself wrong

Comment: Asking "is it possible" is not a great question, as the answer can simply be "yes" or "no". See this [meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270933/should-i-answer-is-it-possible-type-of-questions). If you've tried to do it in JavaScript and can't seem to get the programming right, we can help you with that. That said, yes, it is definitely possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two dimensional arrays are supported trough almost all program languages out there including *JavaScript* and *PHP*. 
The only difference between the languages is the user input and output interface and the speed of the calculations.

So to answer your exact question - it is possible with both *JavaScript* and *PHP*.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/JavaScript/Array2D.htm) how to work with 2d arrays in JavasScript.

Comment: A nit-pick: JS doesn't support multi-dimensional arrays (since arrays are actually objects in JS), you can emulate them with nested arrays though.